# A technicality in the definition of a uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

> A function $f:(M,\ d)\to(N,\ \rho)$ is said to be uniformly continuous
>    if given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $\rho(f(x),\
>  f(y))<\epsilon$ for any $x,\ y\in M$ with $d(x,\ y)<\delta$.

Could we have a uniformly continuous function where for each $\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. the condition $x,\ y\in M$ with $d(x,\ y)<\delta$ is never satisfied and thus the definition holds vacuously?

Comment: "for each $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. the condition $x,y \in M$ with $d(x,y) < \delta$ is never satisfied". what does that have to do with $\epsilon$?

Comment: Strictly yes, because if $M$ is empty, any function on $M$ is uniformly continuous (and there is only one metric on $M$). But if $M$ has even one element $x$, then, rather tautologously, $d(x, x) < \delta$ for all $\delta > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this would hold is if $M$ is a discrete set like $\mathbb Z$, in which case yes any function with domain $M$ is vacuously uniformly continuous.

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood the question - I may have, because it makes logical sense, yet it seems oddly elusive - the questioner requires the condition $d(x,\ y)<\delta$ *never* to be satisfied, not even when $x = y$; and this requires $M$ to be empty.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Yes, that would be true. But in spirit I feel like the person asking the question had something more like $\mathbb Z$ in mind.